# Difference between *+ and * when matching a class in AspectJ?

Tags: java, aop, aspectj, pointcut

Given these pointcuts taken from the following resource:

http://maverick-amey.blogspot.ru/2007/12/using-cflow-and-cflowbelow-in-pointcuts.html

```
pointcut methodCalls() : 
                     call(public void Foo.*(..)) ;

pointcut methodCallFromWebTier() : 
                     methodCalls() && cflow(call(* com.webtier.*+.*(..)));
```

The `methodCallFromWebTier` pointcut is supposed to match all the *calls made to any public method of the `Foo` class with any arguments which returns void* **provided that** (the *&&* operator) the call *is inside the control flow of any call made to a method of*:

- Any class (and its subclasses) in the ***com.webtier*** package;
- Any abstract class (its subclasses) in the ***com.webtier*** package;
- Any interface implementation in the ***com.webtier*** package of any interface in the ***com.webtier*** package;

Now, if the pointcut would have been this instead:

```
pointcut methodCallFromWebTier() : 
                     methodCalls() && cflow(call(* com.webtier.*.*(..)));
```

Therefore without the **+** subtype TypePattern operator, would the pointcut be the same? I mean, it still matches *everything* (any class, abstract class subclass, interface implementation) provided that this *everything* is inside the ***com.webtier*** package, so I don't really see the usage for the **+** sign here...

Am I wrong? Are there some edge cases that perhaps I don't see?

Is the plus sign really necessary in this example?

Thanks for the attention!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plus would make a difference if you are working with types that subclass a type in the `com.webtier` package but are not in the `com.webtier` package. The plus would mean that those types would also be considered when computing cflow. If that doesn't happen in your application then the plus makes no difference.

It also makes a difference whether your Foo class is in the `com.webtier` package. If it is then calls to it are always in the cflow of `call(* com.webtier.*+.*(..))`. And if that were the situation I'd probably use `cflowbelow` instead of `cflow`.

Comment: With `but are not in the com.webtier package` you mean that even a class `com.any.other.package.WebTierTypeSubclass` which calls a method of `Foo` in any of its methods' execution flow will match if the class extends a class of the `com.webtier` package or implements an interface of the `com.webtier` package?

Comment: Yes, a call made from `com.any.other.package.WebTierTypeSubclass` if that type extends a type in `com.webtier` (or implements an interface from it) then `*+` will catch it, `*` will not.  Additionally, if you wish to also consider types in  sub packages like `com.webtier.somesubpackage.Bar` you ought to use `..`: `call(* com.webtier..*+.*(..))`